# Why is the border not shown?

Tags: css

**CSS:**

```
.num{
       z-index:8;
       background-color:#ffd200 ;
       width: 180px;
       height: 47px;
       color: #ffd200;
       border:#ffd200 double 6px; 
       border-radius: 20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="ll">
    <table id="num">
        <tr >
            <td class="num"></td>
            <td class="num"> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Given that setup, why is the border not visible?

Comment: We need your HTML and more or your CSS.

Comment: Why does the border not seem what?

Comment: I could imagine that `seem` is used in the sense of `appear` here (speaking as non-native English speaker, at least both can be translated to the same word in German (though with different meaning)).

Comment: Yes I do not speak English so well ...
i aa edit the first post...

Answer (score 4):

If you're asking why you can't see the border, it's because you've set the colour of the border (and the colour of the text, for that matter) to be the same as the back-ground colour of the element, so it just blends in.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SsfCC/) to illustrate it - changing the colour of the border makes it appear.

Modifying the CSS to something such as this:

```
.num {
    background-color:#ffd200 ;
    color: #ffd200;
    border: #ffffff double 6px;
}
```

would cause the border to appear. This will create an element with the orange background and a white border, rather than an orange background with the same orange border.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts Good point - edited to add possible CSS that will cause the border to actually show.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the border if the border-color differs to background-color!

Comment: the background color of the page is black and the color of the border is yellow...